# Optimal dispersion of points in the unit disk

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

I would like to know if there is an explicit formula to determine, for a fix integer $N>1$, the supremum among $N$ points inside the unit disk $D$, of their minimum distance:

$d(N)=\sup_{\{x_1,\dots,x_N\}\subset D}\min_{1\le j<k\le N}|x_j-x_k|$

First values of $N$ are easy, but things become more elaborated as $N$ grows. Maybe there is an asymptotic expression as $N$ tends to infinity?

Thanks!

Comment: Establishing lower bounds should be okay, but I don't think there's an explicit formula. Assuming this is in $\mathbb R^2$, you can try to express the radius of the smallest disk that contains at least $N$ points of a triangular grid. Right now I can't think of a better configuration.

Comment: Thank you. I think that taking disjoint balls of radius $d/2$ filling concentric rings of size $d$ one can get a lower bound like $1/\sqrt{N}$ and playing a bit with the area of intersections of disks, also get an upper bound like $2\sqrt{2}/\sqrt{N}$ and that this is the right asymptotic behavior. That is $d(N)\approx1/\sqrt{N}$.

Comment: This is in fact an old problem. See the best results [here](http://hydra.nat.uni-magdeburg.de/packing/cci).

Comment: Thanks! This link really helps me a lot.